# Can you change Zurb Foundation's Responsive breakpoint from 640px to 768px?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

Can you change Zurb Foundation's first breakpoint from 640px to 768px?  (are there side effects of doing so, and is it a common and generally accepted practice?).

I think Bootstrap's first breakpoint is 768px and it does allow for more room for a "desktop" browser or tablet.  640px actually might be too cramped to fit in all things, and it goes all the way to 1024px, so it is difficult to design for anything in between.

At 640px, we get header elements pushed down the row, so items need to be styled with cramped margin space, and at 900px or so, the margin space are `%` values, so they get expanded but remain somewhat cramped.

Comment: It's a good question. However you should specify what version is Foundation, as Foundation v6 has changed a lot.

Comment: It can be done quite easily if you're using F5.

Comment: @Yass Is it recommended? -- any side effects or cautions?

Comment: Foundation doesn't explicitly prohibit it and I don't see why they would. In their docs, they even mention how you can customise the break points: [Foundation Media Queries](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/media-queries.html). As for side-effects, I haven't noticed anything in my testing, although any issues should be fairly easy to remedy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the SASS version of foundation, it's easy to change the breakpoints. Take a look at the _settings.scss file, here are the few relevant lines:

```
$breakpoints: (
  small: 0,
  medium: 640px,
  large: 1024px,
  xlarge: 1200px,
  xxlarge: 1440px,
);
$breakpoint-classes: (small medium large);
```

So for what you are trying to achieve, you could simply change the value of `medium` to `768`, and if you want, also increase `large`. Note that the array of breakpoint classes doesn't contain `xlarge` and `xxlarge` by default - if you want these additional classes just add them into the array. You can also define your own if you need to.